# Calling external API in SharePoint framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to call the dummy API from SPFX, but I am getting an error, `Failed to fetch`,

```
  this.context.httpClient
  .get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", HttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
    alert("");
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data: any): void => {
    alert("");
    // Process your data here
  }, (err: any): void => {
    // Handle error here
  });
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where are you calling this? on SharePoint workbench or Local workbench?

Comment: on sharepoint workbench

Comment: Your SharePoint site must be loaded over `https` and you are calling insecure `http` request. So the request will get blocked on SharePoint workbench. Instead you can try calling GET call on any of your SharePoint list like `siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items`.

Comment: its working for sharepoint list, also it works for https secured api's...Is there any way to load http request?

Comment: I guess you can call it using jQuery ajax or something. let me check and get back to you.

Comment: I tried using JQuery, but it is giving same error. Is your API is over `http` or you are just exploring how to call `http` APIs? Also I found some [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/SharePoint-PnP-Webcast-Calling-external-APIs-securely-from/td-p/67835) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi). maybe you will find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

As Ganesh mentioned, mixed content is not allowed. The content needs to be loaded over `https`. Having said that, you can use [Cors Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) , a NodeJS proxy  which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

Wouldnt recommed using it for production, but if you just want to test some stuff or do some PoC work, you can see its implementation using `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` in SPFx as below:

```
const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: new Headers(),
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors"
};

this.context.httpClient
  .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", HttpClient.configurations.v1,httpClientOptions)
  .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> =>         
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data: any): void => {
    console.log(data);
    // process your data here
  }, (err: any): void => {
    // handle error here
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your SharePoint site must be loaded over `https` and you are calling insecure `http` request.

So the request will get blocked on SharePoint workbench.

Instead you can try calling GET call on any of your SharePoint list like:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items
```

Or try any other dummy REST API over `https`, like:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
```